# SSRS Reports custom font error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, fonts, dynamics-crm-2013

Example Image

[image: Example Image]

**Our Problem**:
We create Reports with our CRM 2013 Environment over SSRS. We use our Gotham custom font for this reports. They are installed on the Server and they working fine until November 2016. Since then, the reports are no longer displayed correctly (dots and undefined signs). When we use a standard font for the same report it works fine. What could be the reason for this? The only thing I could connect with this are windows updates.

**Our deployment:**
- Dynamics CRM 2013 (SP1 - UR4)
- SQL Server 2014 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.6020.0
Microsoft Analysis Services-Clienttools                     11.0.6020.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                 6.2.9200.16384
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.10.9200.21989
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.36366
Betriebssystem                      6.2.9200

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Did you check to make sure the `Gotham custom font` is still in the `Fonts` folder on the server?

Comment: You mean in the System Preferences -> Fonts? They are installed on the server. The report is not completely broken, some parts are just fine. I upload a example in this thread.